# Singly Linked List struct insert/delete multiple free

Tags: c, struct, malloc, free

Been looking at this code for too long and I am getting gloomy any chance of figuring it out by myself has been lost :( anyone can tell me where am I being stupid? I just don't understand where I am double freeing or possibly allocating incorrectly (which I must bee doing but yeah). I keep getting *** glibc detected *** free(): invalid next size

Am I actually freeing more than I need to or am I just not allocating what I need to allocate in the first place. --sorry for bad indentation can't get this editor to indent correctly

I have structures:

```
typedef int boolean;
typedef char * String;

typedef struct {
    char name[30];
    long ID;
    char address[40];
    char city[20];
    int age;
}Employee;

typedef struct node {
   Employee *anEmployee;
   struct node *next;
}NODE;

typedef struct {
   NODE *head, *tail;
}SLL;
```

insert function--SLL (Singly Linked List)

```
void insert(SLL *list, Employee e){
  printf("insert");

   NODE *temp, *current;

   temp = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
   assert(temp != NULL);

   temp -> anEmployee = (Employee *)malloc(sizeof(Employee *));
   assert(temp -> anEmployee != NULL);

   strcpy(temp -> anEmployee -> name, e.name); 

   temp -> anEmployee -> ID = e.ID;

   strcpy(temp -> anEmployee -> address, e.address); 

   strcpy(temp -> anEmployee -> city, e.city);

   temp -> anEmployee -> age = e.age;

 if (list -> head == NULL) {     /* list is empty */
  list -> head = list -> tail = temp;
  return;
   }
   else { // list is not empty
       list -> tail -> next = temp;
       list -> tail = temp;
          }
 }
```

deleting and freeing memory in delete function as such

```
boolean delete(SLL *list, String str){
  printf("delete");
  NODE *temp, *temp2;
  if (list -> head == NULL) return FALSE;  // list is empty

temp = list -> head;

while ((temp != NULL) && (strcmp(temp -> anEmployee -> name , str) != 0))
   temp = temp -> next;

if (temp == NULL) return FALSE;  // str is not found in the list

// now temp points to the NODE with str in it.  Let us delete it
// from the list

    if ( list -> head == temp) { // temp points to the first NODE
       if (temp -> next == NULL) {  // temp points to the only NODE
           list -> head = list -> tail = NULL;
           free(temp -> anEmployee);
           free(temp);
           return TRUE;
     }
     // temp points to the first NODE but it is not the only NODE
     list -> head = temp -> next;
     free(temp -> anEmployee);
     free(temp);
     return TRUE;
  }

  if (temp -> next == NULL) {  // temp points to the last NODE
      temp = list -> head;
      temp2 = list -> head -> next;
      while(temp2 - > next != NULL){
        temp = temp->next;
        temp2 = temp2 ->next;
    }


       list -> tail = temp ;    
       list -> tail -> next = NULL;
       free(temp2 -> anEmployee);
       free(temp2);
       return TRUE;
  }
       // temp points to some NODE in the middle of the list
      temp2 = temp -> next;
 while(temp2 - > next != NULL){

    temp ->anEmployee = temp2 - > anEmployee // 
    temp = temp->next;
    temp2 = temp2 ->next;
}
    temp ->anEmployee = temp2 - > anEmployee

   list -> tail = temp ;    
   list -> tail -> next = NULL;
   free(temp2 -> anEmployee);
   free(temp2);
   return TRUE;
 }
```

Comment: For the indentation: search-and-replace tabs with four spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in `insert`, You're allocating

```
temp -> anEmployee = (Employee *)malloc(sizeof(Employee *));
```

which only allocates enough memory to hold an `Employee` *pointer*, not an entire `Employee` structure.  You should allocate a block the size of `sizeof(Employee)` for `temp->anEmployee.`

Your calls to `free` make sense insofar as you do want to free `someNode->anEmployee` and `someNode` to completely clean up the memory occupied by an individual node.

You could simplify your `delete` implementation as follows:

```
boolean delete(SLL* list, String str)
{
    NODE* temp = list->head, *prev = NULL;
    while(temp != NULL && strcmp(temp->name, str) != 0) {
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    if(temp == NULL)
        return FALSE;

    if(prev != NULL)
        prev->next = temp->next;

    if(list->head == temp)
        list->head = temp->next;

    if(list->tail == temp)
        list->tail = temp->next;

    free(temp->anEmployee);
    free(temp);
    return TRUE;
}
```

By tracking the node which precedes your find, if any, you can avoid all of the nasty special cases and reduce the core list update to three simple conditional assignments.

Comment: I don't see the case where you are deleting a node in the middle of the list, however that does simplify the rest of my code greatly. --nvm I see.

Answer (score 0):

Not having read all of it, what are the first lines of `delete` supposed to do?

```
  NODE *temp, *temp2; // temp is uninitialized

    if ( list -> head == temp) { // temp points to the first NODE
```

I can't tell what `delete` is supposed to be deleting. It appears that the `str` argument is unused. Do you want to search for a particular record based on `str`, set `temp` to point to it, and then proceed with the code as shown?

Comment: hhm I removed the part where it is searches though the list for str and if it is found it makes temp point to that node, temp2 is needed for the some of the delete cases (should have probably used switch).

Comment: @Wilson: Not to be too argumentative, but this kind of code is just as efficient and far easier to write in C++.

Comment: @Wilson: Again not to be too argumentative, but Unix is just a family of operating systems, which all work quite well with C++. This problem is clearly in the application programming domain. Even if it were part of the OS kernel, even more reason to use the right tool for the job to achieve *reliability*. Mac OS X is first-class UNIX and uses C++ in the kernel and objective-C in userspace—so what?

Answer (score 0):

In insert(), when you allocate `temp->anEmployee`, you're only allocating enough space for the pointer, not the full Employee.

This line:

```
   temp -> anEmployee = (Employee *)malloc(sizeof(Employee *));
```

should be:

```
   temp -> anEmployee = (Employee *)malloc(sizeof(Employee));
```